How to convert from extendedSRGB color to standard sRGB outside of Swift or Objective-C
I am trying to write some code in Python to display a color taken from a Swift program. However, that color is in the extendedSRGB format. extendedSRGB is similar to standard sRGB except RGB values can be outside of the typical 0 to 1 range. Upon further research, it seems that this is an Apple-made color format, so it is not supported in languages other than Swift or Objective-C. Note: it is called extendedSRGBColorSpace in Objective-C.
I attempted to clip the RGB channels using srgb = np.clip(extended_srgb, 0, 1). I also tried taking the absolute value of the channels using srgb = np.abs(extended_srgb). However, neither of these techniques gave the correct color, particularly for shades of green. According to the extendedSRGB Apple Developer docs:

This color space has the same colorimetry as sRGB, but component values below 0.0 and above 1.0 may be encoded in this color space. Negative values are encoded as the signed reflection of the original encoding function. y(x) = sign(x)*f(abs(x))

I tried following this to create a formula for converting extendedSRGB values back into standard sRGB format, but was unable to. When I used this formula, it seemed to convert negative numbers back into negative numbers. I also do not know what f(x) is in this case.
My question is, what exactly is the formula for converting colors in the extendedSRGB format into standard sRGB format? Alternatively, is there any way in Python to convert from extendedSRGB colors to sRGB?

The extended sRGB colorspace is used to describe colors with a larger gamut (Display P3) while still being compatible with sRGB. I think that truncating the components to 0.0 ... 1.0 should be the right approach.

Can you show some examples of how your code incorrectly converts the color? Show the extended sRGB color components, the expected result and the actual result.

I only handled this once long time ago, so I don't have details, but I think you can treat values [0, 1] as is, like normal sRGB, but then for everything else, you need to treat it as HDR, so either clamp them or apply some other gamma transfer function. Take a look here: https://learnopencv.com/high-dynamic-range-hdr-imaging-using-opencv-cpp-python/

The formula you found is the transfer function of the extended sRGB color space, and f(x) is the transfer function of the non-extended sRGB color space. This formula is not how you convert from sRGB to extended sRGB.

@Evan93 What exactly is "an extendedSRGB color taken from a Swift program"? Do you get numbers from it, and if yes, then do you have an example integer or float for us to discuss? Not even clear if here you are dealing with 10-bits per channel or 16-bits or 32-bits...

@Evan93 PS: "When I used this formula, it seemed to convert negative numbers back into negative numbers" A possible solution might be to mask or bit-shift the resulting channel number into range of 8-bits. Bit-Masking would remove the sign. What/How to do the conversion will depend on the bit-depth of your extendedSRGB color... If not sure, then tell us some numbers for primary and secondary hues.
